# find a string from column in pandas dataframe which matches any item from another list of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas data frame DF

```
 A                    
["I need PEN"   
["something went wrong in LAPTOP"      
"I eat MANGO"
"I dont know anything "]
```

and a Python list **matches** `["BAT","PEN","LAPTOP","I","SCHOOL",,,,]`

need a new column B to be added which matches strings from list

[image]

```
df['B']=df['A'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(matchers) + ")",expand=True)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual content, not pictures of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `df.apply` function

```
def fn_apply(x):
    default_list = ["BAT","PEN","LAPTOP","I","SCHOOL"]
    b_list = []
    for item in default_list:
        if item.upper() in x.A.upper().split():
            b_list.append(item)
    return ",".join(b_list)

df['B'] = df.apply(fn_apply, axis=1)
df

    A                                   B
0   I need PEN                          PEN,I
1   something went wrong in LAPTOP      LAPTOP
2   eat MANGO   
3   dont know anythingabout school      SCHOOL
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I am getting this error     if item.upper() in x.text.upper().split():

AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'upper'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Sorry I had changed column name but still the same error

Comment: what's the column name ...text ?

Comment: Yes column name is text

Comment: you have changed so many things. which is not good as per SO. please edit your post with the changes

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.findall` and then `join`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["I need PEN",
                        "something went wrong in LAPTOP",
                        "I eat MANGO",
                        "I dont know anything about school"]})

matches = ["BAT","PEN","LAPTOP","I","SCHOOL"]
pattern = "|".join(f"\\b{i}\\b" for i in matches)

df["B"] = df['A'].str.findall(pattern,flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.join(",")

print (df)

#
                                   A         B
0                         I need PEN     I,PEN
1     something went wrong in LAPTOP    LAPTOP
2                        I eat MANGO         I
3  I dont know anything about school  I,school
```

Comment: i got below error           error: bad character range T-P

Comment: The above work exactly as the sample you posted. If your sample had edge cases, you should include them.

Answer (score 0):

```
with easy pattern
import re
df['B'] = df['A'].str.findall('(' + '|'.join(matches) + ')', flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.join(',')
```

Comment: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: post fulltraceback